# How to deal with this error in Compiled Function?

Tags: numerics, compile

```
compiled = Compile[{mu, sigma, x}, 
   Module[{}, Log@PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, Abs[sigma]], x]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

compiled[0.000001, 0.0000444, 1]
->CompiledFunction::cfn:
```

it seems that the input values's are too small.
does anyone know how to avoid the error in this case?

Added:
Replacing the function with reference to comments, this become faster 10x!(in the whole optimization process including other function) Here is the code.

```
compiled=Compile[{mu, sigma, x}, Module[{}, Log[1 + 1/(E^((x - mu)^2/(2*Abs[sigma]]^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*Abs[sigma]))]], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the term `Exp[-((x-mu)/sigma)^2/2]` in `PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, Abs[sigma]], x]` will cause an underflow for values of `x` whose absolute value of `x-mu` is large compared to `sigma`; the resulting values are just too small to be representable in machine precision.

```
compiled2 = Compile[{mu, sigma, x},
   If[Abs[x - mu] < 26. sigma,
    Evaluate[Log@PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, Abs[sigma]], x]],
    0.
    ],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

## Edit

I overlooked the appearance of `Log`. One should expect that it will get rid of the `Exp` in `PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, Abs[sigma]], x]`. But Mathematica does not know that all variables are real values and that `sigma` is also positive. The issue can be resolved by telling her explicitly what your assumptions are. Moreover, `Block`ing the symbols that are needed in the simplification adds at lot of robustness to the code and adding the options `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True,` allows for fast evaluation on long lists:

```
compiled3 = Block[{x, mu, sigma},
   With[{code = FullSimplify[
       Log@PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, Abs[sigma]], x],
       {x ∈ Reals, mu ∈ Reals, sigma > 0}
       ]},
    Compile[{{mu, _Real}, {sigma, _Real}, {x, _Real}},
     code,
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
    ]
   ];
```

Here is a usage and timing example:

```
n = 20000000;
μ = RandomReal[{-0.00001, 0.00001}, n];
σ = RandomReal[{0, 2 0.0000444}, n];
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
compiled3[μ, σ, x]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.990

Also interesting to know: Since all the functions involved are vectorized right from the start, it is actually faster *not to compile the code*:

```
Block[{x, mu, sigma},
  f = {mu, sigma, x} \[Function] Evaluate[FullSimplify[
      Log@PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, Abs[sigma]], x],
      {x ∈ Reals, mu ∈ Reals, sigma > 0}
      ]
     ]
  ];
b = f[μ, σ, x]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[(a - b)/a]]
```

> 0.869
>
> 1.59214*10^-13

## By the way:

`` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[compiled] `` showed that there was a call to `MainEvaluate` in the compiled function. So, you probably would not have experienced any speedup. `Evaluate` repairs this.

Comment: Why Abs[x-mu]<26. sigma?

Comment: Because `Exp[-27.^2]` causes an underflow. Moreover, `Exp[-26.^2/2]` has already magnitude $10^{-147}$, so setting it to `0.` will most likely cause no harm.

Comment: `Sqrt[-Log[$MinMachineNumber]]` evaluates to `26.6157`, so `26.` is actually a pretty good cutoff value.